# Redirecting to a specific file from all subdomains using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect traffic to a specific file when user requests a.domain.com/index.php or b.domain.com/index.php it will redirect to domain.com/index.php

Comment: You asked this [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742244/setting-up-apache-to-redirect-all-subdomains-to-a-specific-file) half an hour ago.

Comment: @bcmcfc it is also asked by me but no any answer

Comment: @user3081534 so wait for someone to answer, don't create duplicates

Comment: @user3081534: Don't ask duplicate questions and wait for the answers. It is better you delete that question.

Comment: or tell me how to make a wildcard subdomain?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: I want all subdomains not only a or b

Comment: Also you need to delete that dup question first.